# HTML 5 Browser and resolutions compatibility over XHTML

Tags: css, html, xhtml, margin

When I started coding for websites over 10 years ago I programmed in XHTML but the company I joined later was using HTML 4. 
After a while they started using XHTML 1.0 Transitional and we found that browser compatibility suddenly became a lot easier, presumably since we were much closer to standards mode.

I currently have a website and I need to have links which change the margins sometimes. I find of different computers, even if they use the same resolution and browser that the margin or font size in the margin (which is set at a fixed size) still varies and when I change the margins, it may look correct on one computer, but not on another.
This website is currently using XHTML 1.0 Transitional. If I change the HTML 5 which is standards mode, could this solve the problem?

Comment: The whole "transitional" thing is obsolete nowadays.  Your entire doctype should just be <!DOCTYPE html>.  Start from there and adjust your CSS accordingly.  Just remember that anything inside an anchor tag will need its own definition.

Comment: I was using JavaScript to adjust the margins.

Comment: Javascript to adjust margins? Ehm... not sure what to say there. You are sure that the browser where the result is unsatisfactory also has JavaScript enabled?

Answer (score -1):

Aaah, XHTML, doctypes and quirks mode. Those were the days.

Although we have come a long way since then, browsers still do handle things differently from time to time. Once way of minimising this is to use something like a [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) or [normalize](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/).

To answer your original question, yes, you really should use HTML5 doctype and follow HTML5 standards these days.

Comment: I know I need to use HTML 5. I'm just learning about what I need to do to keep a website I'm testing to look exactly the same.

Is HTML 5 likly to sort out the problem of my website?

Comment: It's difficult to say, your question is quite vague. If you can post an example of the problem you're having this would help.

Comment: The story on this page is quite long:
http://www.candle-light.co.uk/flickering/travok.html

So I tried to include some links to different sections in the story:
http://www.candle-light.co.uk/flickering/travok-contents.html

The links don't go to the same page on different computers even if they're using the same resolution, settings and browser.

Comment: So if I've got this right, all the paragraphs of the story are on the page. Clicking on the links adjusts the margins to show the correct paragraph? I don't think switching to HTML5 will help you here, although some HTML5 features could possible make it a little easier. e.g customer data types, history API. I can't replicate the problme you're having though, so I don't think I can help much more.

Comment: Okay. I was just wondering. I tried using anchors as well but that screwed the layout up.
You're correct. The index of links is on a different page to the story but the whole story is on the same page and I was linking to certian pages but when found the pargraphs were on different pages on different computers.
You don't have any ideas of other ways I might be able to use links do you?

Comment: It seems like a complicated page, so retro-fitting something could prove challenging. If I was starting this from scratch, one solution would be to section the content into chapters/pages. Give each page an attribute `data-page-number="56"`. You could then show and hide that page with some javascript. You could then use a hash value or query string in the url, to link directly to the page. on page load a function would grab the hash or query string, then show the appropriate section. This could also be done using a framework that supports single page apps (angular/ember/react).

Comment: I'm not sure I dare click those links now.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean Mr. Lister?